# How can I get it pubkey with Openssl:ECDSA

Tags: openssl, ecdsa

I want to use the basic func of ecdsa:keygen\sign\verify.
After reading the doc [openssl/ecdsa](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ECDSA_do_sign.html)

I write this:

```
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/obj_mac.h> // for NID_secp192k1\  
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int ret;
  ECDSA_SIG *sig;
  EC_KEY *eckey;
  eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
  EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey);
  sig = ECDSA_SIG_new();
  if (eckey == NULL)
    printf("err1");
  unsigned char dgst[] = "test";
  unsigned char res[32];
  SHA256(dgst, 32, res);
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
  {
    printf("%02x", res[i]);
  }
  sig = ECDSA_do_sign(res, 32, eckey);
  if (sig == NULL)
    printf("err\n");
  printf("\n");
  ret = ECDSA_do_verify(res, 32, sig, eckey);
  printf("%d\n", ret);
}
```

This code worked. However, in `ECDSA_do_Verify` the input is eckey, including a public key and private key. But I just want to use pubkey to verify. So how can I achieve this goal?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
...
unsigned char *ptr = NULL;
int n = i2d_EC_PUBKEY (eckey, &ptr); // 'export' a representation of the publickey 
const unsigned char *copy = ptr;
EC_KEY * ecpub = d2i_EC_PUBKEY (NULL, &copy, n); // 'import' it to a new object
OPENSSL_free (ptr); // for real code, not needed for a test hack like yours
```

Of course in a real application you would need to store the keypair someplace, and probably get a certificate for the publickey, which the former probably and the latter definitely already provide an externalized publickey to be read back in.

PS: I forgot to say, but you are using as input to `SHA256()` a purported 32-byte buffer `dgst`, but `dgst` is only 5 bytes, so this is technically undefined behavior (and can do anything) and in practice will probably use whatever random garbage happens to be in memory following `dgst`, which makes your results unreproducible and unverifiable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer！And I notice the mistaks I hava made in SHA256(),now i correct it.As you say that in real application,Ｉneed to store it,in my project I need to return it use unsignchar* form.However,I also use another Crytography scheme generate Keypair,so i need the length of EC_KEY,how can i get the length.I try to use `EC_KEY_priv2oct()`,but i failed.

Comment: I may know that the function`i2d_EC_PUBKEY (eckey, &ptr);`tell me the length Pubkey need,and malloc corresponding space for point ptr?I follow it can get the ECDSA_SIG.However,I do not find the func to get EC_KEY pair.

Comment: `i2d` returns the length in bytes *of the representation OpenSSL uses* which is X.509 SPKI in DER, and `i2d` with `ptr==NULL` allocates the space with `OPENSSL_malloc` which is why as I said it should be freed with `OPENSSL_free` unless the program immediately exits. Other _software_ implementing EC may use different representations and if you want to interchange with them you need to specify exactly what you are doing. If you want to use other _algorithms_ (not EC) that's a different question than you asked.